How do you find the intersection between 2 complex shapes?
One thing I've done to find if two perfect circles intersect is to compare the radii of both circles to the distance between them, which isn't complicated at all. However, for non-circle shapes, I don't know how you would find an intersection due to the changing radii of the shapes.
I'm making a hitbox system for a game and am using math-defined hitboxes that match what the sprites they belong to will look like when they're rendered. Here is a desmos graph showing what the hitboxes look like:

The red and orange lines make up the first shape, and the blue and purple ones combine to create the other shape. Both shapes use the exact same formulas and dimensions. With the changing radii, how would I find whether or not the shapes intersect, and at what points?

If you have a function, it usually separates the in-shape points from the out-shape points by the sign of the value of a function for a point.
